# Porting a VBA Type / C struct to a Python ctypes.Structure: array of strings with fixed length

Tags: python, c, vba, struct, ctypes

I am trying to port a piece of VBA code to Python. This effort includes calling a function in a Windows DLL. The function requires a pointer to a C struct (in VBA, they are called "Type") as a parameter. The mentioned struct contains strings of fixed length as well as arrays of strings of fixed length. I am struggling with finding a way to express this in Python using ctypes.

The original VBA code contains statements like this:

```
Public Type elements
    elementA As String * 48
    elementB(3) As String * 12
End Type
```

This may be represented in the following way in C, I think:

```
struct elements
{
    char elementA[48];
    char elementB[4][12];
}
```

What I have tried so far in Python:

```
import ctypes

class elements(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("elementA", ctypes.create_string_buffer(48)), 
        ("elementB", ctypes.create_string_buffer(12) * 4)
        ]
```

I can successfully declare elementA, though declaring elementB fails with

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'c_char_Array_12' and 'int'"

How can this be done the right way?

---

**UPDATE #1**

I can successfully declare the following:

```
import ctypes

class elements(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("elementA", ctypes.c_char * 48), 
        ("elementB", ctypes.c_char * 12 * 4)
        ]
```

elementA exposed a "value" property, while I can not find a way to work with elementB. How can I read its contents or change them?

---

**UPDATE #2**

I think I understand the behaviour.

```
>>> e = elements()
>>> e.elementA
''
>>> e.elementA = 'test'
>>> e.elementA
'test'
>>> e.elementB
<__main__.c_char_Array_12_Array_4 object at 0x9878ecc>
>>> e.elementB[0][:] == '\x00' * 12
True
>>> e.elementB[0][:]
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> e.elementB[0][:] = 'test'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Can only assign sequence of same size
>>> e.elementB[0][:] = 'test' + '\x00' * 8
>>> e.elementB[0][:]
'test\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> testB = 'abcde'
>>> e.elementB[0][:] = testB + '\x00' * ( ctypes.sizeof(e.elementB[0]) - len(testB) )
>>> e.elementB[0][:]
'abcde\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> e.elementB[0][:].rstrip('\x00')
'abcde'
>>> e.elementB[0].value
'abcde'
>>> e.elementB[0].value = 'abcdef'
>>> e.elementB[0][:]
'abcdef\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

*(This question refers to Python 2.6 and 2.7.)*

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for your help. I worked your comment into my question, yet, I have difficulties using it. The 2D-char-array does not expose anything like a "value" property and I can not figure out how to read from or write to this array.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks again. I think I now understand the behaviour - see the last update to my question. Do you want to wrap this up into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`create_string_buffer` is a convenience function to create a `c_char` array instance. However, a field definition requires a C type, not an instance. For example:

```
import ctypes

class elements(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("elementA", ctypes.c_char * 48), 
                ("elementB", ctypes.c_char * 12 * 4)]
```

Say you have a C function defined as follows:

```
lib.func.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(elements)]
```

To call this function, pass an instance of `elements` using `byref`:

```
e = elements()
lib.func(ctypes.byref(e))
```

Accessing a 1-D `c_char` array field, such as `elementA`, is special cased to return a Python string. But accessing a 2-D array, such as `elementB`, returns a ctypes `Array` instance. In the case of `elementB` there are 4 rows, each containing 12 columns.

```
>>> len(e.elementB)
4
>>> map(len, e.elementB)
[12, 12, 12, 12]
```

`sizeof` returns the size of an array in bytes. For example the buffer for `elementB` consists of 48 `c_char` elements, which are 1 byte each:

```
>>> ctypes.sizeof(e.elementB)
48
```

The `c_char` arrays of `elementB`, as character arrays, are special cased to have `value` and `raw` attributes. Getting the `value` attribute creates a Python string that treats the array as a null-terminated C string. The `raw` attribute returns the entire length. You can also assign Python strings using these attributes, and both accept a string with a null in it.

```
>>> e.elementB[3].value = 'abc\x00def'
>>> e.elementB[3].value
'abc'
>>> e.elementB[3].raw
'abc\x00def\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Or slice the array to get a substring:

```
>>> e.elementB[3][:]
'abc\x00def\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> e.elementB[3][4:7]
'def'
```

`c_wchar` arrays only have the `value` attribute, which returns a `unicode` string. You can set `value` with either a `unicode` string or (in Python 2) an 8-bit string. An 8-bit string is decoded using the current ctypes encoding, which defaults to `'mbcs'` on Windows and `'ascii'` otherwise. `set_conversion_mode` (Python 2) sets the default encoding:

```
>>> s = (ctypes.c_wchar * 12)()
>>> v = u'\u0100'.encode('utf-8')
>>> v
'\xc4\x80'
>>> s.value = v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: 
ordinal not in range(128)
```

```
>>> old_mode = ctypes.set_conversion_mode('utf-8', 'strict')
>>> old_mode
('ascii', 'strict')
```

Assigning `'\xc4\x80'` works now that the conversion encoding is set to UTF-8:

```
>>> s.value = v
>>> s.value
u'\u0100'
>>> s[:]
u'\u0100\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Arrays are iterable:

```
for row in e.elementB:
    row[:] = 'abcdefghijkl'

>>> print '\n'.join(row[::-1] for row in e.elementB)
lkjihgfedcba
lkjihgfedcba
lkjihgfedcba
lkjihgfedcba
```

ctypes data types support Python's buffer protocol for inter-operation with other types:

```
>>> bytearray(e.elementB)
bytearray(b'abcdefghijklabcdefghijklabcdefghijklabcdefghijkl')

>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.frombuffer(e.elementB, dtype='uint8')
array([ 97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108,  97,
        98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108,  97,  98,
        99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108,  97,  98,  99,
       100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108], dtype=uint8)
```